# Ethereum geth check transactions with python

Tags: python, ethereum, geth

my questions is...
I want to run a fullnode like geth to save transactions of my different eth addresses with python into a database. But I have no idea how to do that. Are there any special libraries or does geth have a Json interface?
Thank you for your ideas

PS: I know i can also use ethscan.io, but i dont want use services like this.

Comment: You might be looking for Web3.py, which enables you to connect to your full node via python: http://web3py.readthedocs.io/en/stable/

Comment: Have you, this site is very helpful, but i cant find a method whitch give my all transactions from a address. I find just a Method where i have to put the tx_hash

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no direct way to do this (in an efficient way, more about that later) by using Web3.py, or any Web3 implementation at this time.

Really the only way is to use Etherscan or something else.

Now on to the really inefficient way. You do this by using a for loop to go through all the blocks. If you narrowed it down to like 10 blocks, you wouldn't have an issue, but if you wanted to go through all 6,000,000 (I think we are there now), it would take too long. If you really want to go this route, look at https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/2531/common-useful-javascript-snippets-for-geth/3478#3478

Comment: Thx for your opinion. By the way, do you know why geth is never 100% syncing? Am am at 99,9888...% it left almost 70-100 blocks its my internet connection the problem or is this normal ?

Comment: Not a problem. the reason it is never at 100% is because new blocks are mined every second, sometimes multiple a second, so it is always downloading blocks. Also, if you think my answer was helpful, please upvote it and mark it as the correct answer.

Comment: Ok I already knew that never can be 100%, I thought it will be 1 or 2 blocks but I am always 50-100 blocks behind. That can't be a activ Full node

Comment: Go to fast.com and tell me what your internet speed is.

Comment: Also are you using an SSD? If so, it is not supported. You need to use light mode.

Comment: Reference is here https://github.com/ethereum/go-ethereum/issues/16218

An HDD can not keep up.

Comment: It almost 25 mbits

Comment: Are you using an SSD?

Comment: Ah ok. That's the problem. No I have just use a normal hdd to try it

Comment: How can I start the light mode?

Comment: Just geth ? What I should use?

Comment: Try `geth --syncmode "light"`

Comment: Ok, but what are exactly the differences ?

Comment: How about you create a new question asking the difference just so if someone needs help in the future they can find it. I will answer it right away.

Comment: Not a problem at all. Please just create separate questions and I will be happy to answer them all to the best of my ability!

Comment: An other question how can I check the pending transactions in geth. I can't find any method...

Comment: Please  create another question.